# Passport OAuth login redirect not working in production. (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, discord

I am having a problem with express and react communicating correctly in production. I am using Discord Oauth to log users in and in development it works fine, the user makes a request to the `/auth/login` route on the client side (port 3000) and it redirects them to the `auth/login` route in my express server (port 5000). I knew from the beggining that this would be limited to development but i have a few other routes that work in production and i cant seem to get my passport `/auth/redirect` route to work.

**Route:** `/auth/login`

this route just renders the prebuilt Discord Oauth URL which can be configured [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) in your apps Oauth2 page.

**Route:** `/auth/redirect`

```
app.get('/auth/redirect', passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    successRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard'
  }), (req, res, ) => {
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

I know that all of my code is correct becuase i have tested extensively in development, production just seems to be the issue, note it is a create react app, so i basically just need to know how to make the `GET /auth/redirect` route working in production, i am correctly serving my react app through express with the following code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you in advance!